# How to divide values in two columns in IBM doors

Tags: ibm-doors

Hello hope everyone is fine, so I want a column that shows the percentage value for example if I have 1 column which has a value a and 2nd column which has value b I want a column which shows a/b*100,I have attached a screenshot hope it helps. Thanks in advance. Sorry if I had caused any inconvenience.

Lets say col1:1 3 4 6 etc
col2 has : 7 9 6 10 etc
col3 must be 1/7 multiplied by 100 3/9 multiplied 100...
[image: So i want each and every value in both these column divided and multiplied by hundred]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DXL attribute 'product' and paste the following code

//Go to Edit -> Attributes, select 'Product' attribute; select Edit and check the checkbox 'DXL attribute', click the 'Browse' button and paste the following code

//Press F5 to refresh DXL attributes

//Or 'Tool -> Refresh DXL attributes' to refresh DXL attributes

```
obj.attrDXLName = intOf(obj."col1""")*100/intOf(obj."col2""")
```